# Expressions in Case Statements - Conditional WHERE

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am looking for a work-around or a solution for a situation where I only want to execute an expression based on two conditions using a CASE statement. I have written some mock pseudo code to illustrate what I am trying to do.

```
WHERE (RN = 1)
AND
    CASE
        WHEN (@ApplicationName  '' OR @ApplicationGroup  '')
            THEN 

                AND (
                    @AppFilterType = 'Groups' AND [GroupName].[Name] IN (SELECT StringValue FROM [StarTeam].[dbo].fn_CSVToTable(@ApplicationGroup))
                    OR
                    @AppFilterType = 'Apps' AND [AppName].[Name] IN (SELECT StringValue FROM [StarTeam].[dbo].fn_CSVToTable(@ApplicationName))
                )
    END
```

This is the idea, only execute the condition if `@ApplicationName` and/or `@ApplicationGroup` have a value.

I am using this in a T-SQL Stored Procedure running on SQL Server 2005.

Is this possible in some way?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE RN = 1
    AND (
            (@ApplicationName = '' and @ApplicationGroup = '')
            or (
                    (@AppFilterType = 'Groups' AND [GroupName].[Name] IN (SELECT StringValue FROM [StarTeam].[dbo].fn_CSVToTable(@ApplicationGroup)))
                    or (@AppFilterType = 'Apps' AND [AppName].[Name] IN (SELECT StringValue FROM [StarTeam].[dbo].fn_CSVToTable(@ApplicationName)))
                )
        )
```

Comment: Ahh, so no need for a Case Statement at all. Let me give it a go. thanks!

Comment: Alright, I have tested this. No errors but not behaving as expected. Maybe I am missing something. In the case where both of my params have no values I do not want the block to execute at all. So it should behave like the block is not there at all. Right now when I run this I get no results back from my record set. The idea is that I should get everything back. When I comment out the AND block I get all the records back. Can you think of what I may not be doing right?

Comment: Try the revised `WHERE` clause above.